# How does Entity Framework manage database connections?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Assume, the following is our BusinessLayer :

```
public class DatabaseInteract
{
    //`NewsEntities` is our ObjectContext
    public List<News> GetAllNews()
    {
         return new NewsEntities().News.OrderByDescending(q => q.RegidtrationDate).ToList();
    }

    public News GetNewsById(int newsId)
    {
         return new NewsEntities().News.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Id== newsId);
    }

    public bool IsNewsExist(int newsId)
    {
         var news = new NewsEntities().News.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Id== newsId);
         return news != null;
     }
}
```

And the following is our Controller in an ASP.NET MVC project :

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
    DatabaseInteract databaseInteract = new DatabaseInteract();
    ViewBag.AllNews = databaseInteract.GetAllNews(id.Value);
    ViewBag.News = databaseInteract.GetNewsById(id.Value);
    ViewBag.IsExist = databaseInteract.IsNewsExist(id.Value);
    return View(model);
}
```

Now, My question is : 
Are we have a new connection to the database during invoking each Business Layer's method ?

**Edit :**

Is the following code good for confidence that we have only one connection to the database in each instance of `DatabaseInteract` Class :

```
public class DatabaseInteract 
{
    readonly NewsEntities _entities = new NewsEntities();

    //`NewsEntities` is our ObjectContext
    public List<News> GetAllNews()
    {
         return _entities.News.OrderByDescending(q => q.RegidtrationDate).ToList();
    }

    public News GetNewsById(int newsId)
    {
         return _entities.News.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Id== newsId);
    }

    public bool IsNewsExist(int newsId)
    {
         var news = _entities.News.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Id== newsId);
         return news != null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: instead of `.FirstOrDefault()` and check for null, there is also [`.Any()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Entity Framework manages a connection pool, which means that EF will reuse connections when possible and only create new ones when it needs to.  Whether or not each call creates a new connection depends on many factors.  So it's hard to say whether any given set of calls will or will not create new connections.

In general, EF does an extremely good job of managing connections, and you shouldn't worry about it unless you know it to be a problem.

Comment: Please see the `Edit` section in my question

Comment: @Mohammad - Your edit doesn't change my answer.  There are a lot of factors that go into how EF uses connections, and it depends on how your app as a whole uses EF.  So no, there is no confidence it will only use one, or any confidence that it will use more than one.  Just relax and don't worry about it.  Connections are managed in a global connection pool, and they are not dependent upon a single instance of your data context.